# Azure B2C Custom Policy token missing info

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have a custom policy setup that validates a phone number when a user signs. The phone number is validated on a separate screen after the user completes their social login. The issue is the token that is generated does not include the phone number. If the user logs out and logs back in, the phone number is then included in the token. How do I get the phone number included in the initial token so the user does not need to log out?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the **strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber** claim, as an outgoing claim in the ID token:

```
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <OutputClaims>
      ...
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="phone_number" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
  </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

Comment: I do not have a claim type with id strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber. I do have signInNames.phoneNumber and that is included as an output below but is not included in token for social logins.

<DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignInWithParts" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.phoneNumber" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>